# List of sources or list of figures with small source

Tags: source

hope you're doing fine.

I've seen all the subjects about my question and tried some still didn't work out as I wanted.

Here's what I'm trying to acheive :
[image]

Right now I only have a list of figure with their captions which is really fine , but I would prefer the source to be smaller and below the caption as in the image show above and also spaced out a bit from the line of the caption (cause sometimes the url is long so it can get confusing.)

Right now here's what I have :

[image]

I'm using a template and I'm still a newbie in latex.But here's the code I inserted in the main document :

[image]

and the code near the image you see in the list of figure, indicating the position of the source:
[image]

Thank you very much for any help provided.Take care.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what it is that you want. It would have been helpful if you had provide an MWE (from `documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) showing what you had done so that we could compile it in order to help you rather than your snippet of a screen shot.

I have tried to produce various scenarios, but I'm not sure which is applicable to your problem.

```
% figsourceprob.tex  SE 576631

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\figsourcefont}{\footnotesize}
\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
  {\leftskip\cftfigindent
    \advance\leftskip\cftfignumwidth
    \rightskip\@tocrmarg
    \figsourcefont#1\protect\par}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\section{A section}

\begin{figure}
\centering
AN ILLUSTRATION
\caption[An illustration \\ Illustration  source] {An illustration}
\end{figure}

\section{Second}

\begin{figure}
\centering
ANOTHER ILLUSTRATION
\caption{Another illustration \hfill\mbox{}  \protect\vspace{\baselineskip} \figsourcefont{Another illustraton  source}}
\end{figure}

\section{Third}

\begin{figure}
\centering
A PICTURE
\caption{A picture}
\figsource{Picture source}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I was not able to produce a multi-line `\caption` but surely someone else can.

[image]

Comment: Hey , sorry really for being late , been busy a bit ,anyway ,from the first picture it looks like it yeah that's what I'm searching for, it wasn't working with an old code so I'm going to try yours.Thank you very much Peter, sure about the code you're right but don't know I couldn't copy it clearly to the forum although it was on  a code box, that's why I made a screenshot, sorry still a newbie

Answer (score 0):

so I tried the third option which I like it but and I've got this result
[image]

I had this issue before with the 2.55em appearing before "picture source" but I don't know how to delete or what's is it.I think it might be because of "@tocrmarg" it looks like it needs another package for my memoir class ?

Also would it be possible to add a little space between figure x.x and x.y (as adding sources might be a lot).Okay here's the code, finally got it to show up entierly in the box ,it the main document but it's a template I've got so I added few on my own,while searching for answers, not really sure if there'all compatible, the code you gave me is also included.

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag} % tells you of any bad LaTeX usage
                                       % must be first thing in class (with the exception of comments)
                                       

\newenvironment{a3_landscape}
{
    \newpage
    \pdfpagewidth=2\pdfpagewidth
    \setlength{\textwidth}{4cm+\textwidth*2} % need calc pkg
    \headwidth=\textwidth
    \hsize=\textwidth
}
{
    \newpage
    \pdfpagewidth=.5\pdfpagewidth
    \setlength{\textwidth}{\textwidth-4cm}
    \textwidth=.5\textwidth
    \headwidth=\textwidth
    \hsize=\textwidth
}

%% There is one option you should define; oneside or twoside
%% Use twoside for your viva docs (examiners hate long docs they need to carry around)
%% and oneside for the final thing you submit to the library.  Note that margins will
%% change accordingly

\documentclass[french]{um}  % custom University of Malta project/dissertation/thesis
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{incgraph}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\raggedbottom


%% **************** (Your) Packages (Start) ******************

% \listfiles % uncomment this to know which packages you are using
              % the list of packages will be in the bottom of the .log file

%% Note that packges may already be loaded from the um (and memoir) classes.
%% Do not add your packages to the template, but rather add them here.

\usepackage{blindtext} %% for some dummy text, remove in your writeup


%% ***************** (Your) Packages (End) *******************


%% **************** (Your) Data (Start) ******************
\title{Machine Learning\\Approaches to the\\Blockchain}  % use \\ here otherwise you get a justified title
                                                    % note capitalization of the title (only common 
                                                    % words in lower case)
\tagline{some hyped-up tagline}                     % tag line
\author{Jean-Paul Ebejer}                           % your name
\authorID{123456M}                           % your University Identifier
\supervisor{Dr Zhivago}                             % your supervisor(s) name - no . in Dr
\cosupervisor{Dr Who}                               % your cosupervisor(s) name - no . in Dr ** OPTIONAL ** 
                                                    % simply comment out the above line if absent
\department{Department of Alchemy}                  % your department (e.g. Artifical Intelligence)
\faculty{Faculty of Something}                      % your faculty (e.g. ICT)
\degree{M.Sc.\ in Your Degree}                      % the degree you are reading
                                                    % note the \ after the dot, so not to consider it a fullstop
\doctype{dissertation}                              % the type of document (fyp, dissertation, thesis)
\degreedate{June, 2019}                        % when did you submit -- officially after your corrections !
%%\subjectcode{ICS5200}          
%% ***************** (Your) Data (End) *******************


%% ******** (Your) Document Settings (Start) *************

% You should have an images directory in every chapX subdir
% NOTE:  Trailing / for subdirs is required.
\graphicspath{{./images/}{./chap1/images/}}   % Paths where to look for images, if defined "images" must always be there as it holds the images in-use by the template.

\makeindex

%% ********* (Your) Document Settings (End) **************

% DOCTOR'S (JP) ORDERS: MAKE SURE TO READ MY TWO BLOG ENTRIES WITH
% CONTENT AND LaTeX TIPS FOR YOUR WRITE-UP.  THESE ARE BASED ON  
% EXAMINER'S FEEDBACK
%
% URLS:
% https://bitsilla.com/blog/2019/03/content-tips-for-your-dissertation-or-project-write-up/
% https://bitsilla.com/blog/2019/01/latex-tips-for-your-dissertation-or-project-write-up/

% end the preamble and start the document

\begin{document}
\frontmatter 
     \includepdf[pages=-]{garde.pdf}
    \renewcommand*\acknoname{Remerciements}
    \input{frontmatter/acknowledgements}   % include an acknowledgements.tex file
    \input{frontmatter/abstract}\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
    \renewcommand*\contentsname{Sommaire}
    \tableofcontents*\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
     \renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig}
      \renewcommand{\tablename}{Tableau}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\figsourcefont}{\footnotesize}
\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
  {\leftskip\cftfigindent
    \advance\leftskip\cftfignumwidth
    \rightskip\@tocrmarg
    \figsourcefont#1\protect\par}%
  }%
}


\makeatother

%% Note: always use \input as you cannot nest \includes (amongst other things)
\pagestyle{umpage}
\mainmatter 
    \includepdf[pages=-]{intro page.pdf}
    \input{chap1/introduction_main} 
    \includepdf[pages=-]{th.pdf}
    \input{chap2/background_and_lit_overview_main}
    \input{chap3/materials_and_methods_main}
    \input{chap4/results_and_discussion_main}
      \includepdf[pages=-]{exp page.pdf}
    \input{chap5/evaluation_main}
    \input{chap6/conclusions_main}
    \appendix
        \input{appA/Annexe A}     % these are just test names as I didn't know what you'd want
         \input{appB/Annexe B}
        \listoffiguresource
      
    \listoffigures*\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
    \listoftables*\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi

{\backmatter
    % Bibliography
    \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
    \bibliographystyle{um-plainnat} %% specific plainnat does not show url for articles
    {\footnotesize\bibliography{chap1/introduction_biblio,chap2/background_and_lit_overview_biblio}}
    \printindex
}

\includepdf[pages=-]{biblio.pdf}

\end{document}

%%% The End %%%
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what you have posted is not an answer, it is a question so you need to post it as a question. I have no access to the `um` class so cannot process your MWE although you hinted that it might be based on the `memoir` class. However I see that you have found out how to post LaTeX code instead of a screenshot. Well done.

Comment: yeah sorry Peter I know I kinda messed up, I'm still discovering latex and the forum. I'll try to figure how to fix it and if I can't I'll just make a list of source alone with no list of figures combined with sources.